# Arduino Due in Atmel Studio 6.1. without Visualmikro

Tags: arduino, sbrk

I prefer the tutorial from http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-atmel-studio-6-with-arduino-projects/ over Visualmikro because I love being able to jump inside the arduino functions and modify them without having to install any kind of plugin.

I tried compile my project following the tutorial but it won't work: "undefined reference to _sbrk". Which sounds like a really bad linker error to me?

I needed to adapt a few things because the tutorial was written for an older version of the IDE and is targeting AVRs and not SAMs:

GNU C++/Symbols

- List item
- F_CPU = 84000000L
- ARDUINO=154

GNU C++/Directories

- [...]\Arduino\hardware\arduino\sam\cores\arduino
- [...]\Arduino\hardware\arduino\sam\variants\arduino_due_x (had to change this one)
- [...]\Arduino\hardware\arduino\sam\system\libsam

ARM/GNU Linker/Libraries

- libcoreDue.a (I added Due, to be able to identify the type of arduino)
- libsam_sam3x8e_gcc_rel_a
- as well as the paths to those two files.

Any idea what I could have missed?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I would very much like to have an answer to this important question. May I ask if you already have succeeded today?

Comment: @user3293156 I'm afraid: No. But you might find interesting that jumping into functions should also work with VisualMikro as well. If you're looking for a native ARM board, I can recommend the STM32 family: The Hardware-Debugger is cheap (~20€), there are good tutorials out there, and a free IDE (CooCox CoIDE) is also available. The board I ended up working with is the Olimexino-STM32.